# How can I import multiple CSVs to preset sheets?

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, import, google-sheets-api, string-comparison

I have some CSV files on my G-drive that I want to import to preset sheets, based on file names. For example,

1. I have CSV files named: "REP1-abc", "REP2-bcd", "REP3-cde",...
2. I have spreadsheet with sheets named: "REP1", "REP2", "REP3",...

Target is to take first four letters of file name to match correct sheet name and import it to that sheet.
Im new in this so i will appreciate any tips on how to compare those two names.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Loading CSVs

```
function loadcsvs() {
  const fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder id");
  const files = fldr.getFileByType(MimeType.CSV);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName());
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    let sname = file.getName().slice(0,4);
    let idx = shts.indexOf(sname);
    if(~idx) {
      let sht = ss.getSheetByName(shts[idx]);
      let vs = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString())
      sht.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
    }
  }
}
```